Why does external floppy drive recognizes disc but can’t view files?
A friend lent me an external floppy drive unit.
It works on his PC.

It is plug ’n’ play.
There is no driver available for download for this unit.
I connect it to the USB port on my PC.
Norton Anti-Virus recognizes the 3.5” disc.
Norton scans many existent files for viruses.

However I cannot view any files on the disc.
The drive ( A: )(?) does not appear in Explorer.
I’m using Windows 7.
I tried a few floppy discs and got the same result.
I am now reluctant to buy my own such unit
in fear of getting the same result.
Any insight?

Ignoring the fact that we're troubleshooting floppy disk drives in 2024. If you open the Windows "Disk management" tool, can you see the disk there? It is possible that there is no drive letter assigned to it or that it is not formatted correctly.
Also, it should show up in the "Device Manager". If there is an issue with it, it will most likely appear with a red "X" or something similar on it.
